# pip install python-igraph failed on debian image

Tags: python, docker, debian, igraph

I'm just trying to create a docker image from this Dockerfile.

```
FROM debian:latest

USER root

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV PATH /twecoll:$PATH

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev python-dev python-pip pkg-config libffi-dev libcairo-dev git
RUN pip install python-igraph
RUN pip install --upgrade cffi
RUN pip install cairocffi

RUN git clone https://github.com/jdevoo/twecoll.git
ADD .twecoll /root

WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app

ENTRYPOINT ["twecoll"]
CMD ["-v"]
```

but when running RUN pip install python-igraph, an error appears like this.

Error Message:
[image: Error Message]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try as the [documentation](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/install.html#compiling-using-pip) suggests.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph
```

or

```
pip install –no-binary ‘:all:’ python-igraph
```

Comment: I have tried both but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When you're installing `python-igraph` from `pip` and it can't find a precompiled wheel for your distribution (which it mostly doesn't), `pip` will try to compile the `igraph` binaries for your image, which 1) is error-prone, 2) takes a long time, 3) is the reason you need to install so many build tools and libraries. A better approach is to install `igraph` from the Debian repositories with `apt-get install python-igraph` first, which will install all the necessary requirements including a compiled `igraph`.

This leaves the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

USER root

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV PATH /twecoll:$PATH

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip libffi-dev libcairo-dev git python-igraph
RUN pip install python-igraph
RUN pip install --upgrade cffi
RUN pip install cairocffi

RUN git clone https://github.com/jdevoo/twecoll.git
ADD .twecoll /root

WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app

ENTRYPOINT ["twecoll"]
CMD ["-v"]
```

As you can see I'm just installing `python-igraph`, no more build tools! You may even be able to do something similar for `cairo` and `ffi` but I'm leaving that for you.